# Hibernate-Jcache + Ehcache for non-primary key queries

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

In my Spring Boot 2 application, I configured hibernate-jcache and ehcache for a read-only database like this:

```
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode=ENABLE_SELECTIVE
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.jcache.JCacheRegionFactory
```

with this entity:

```
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
@Entity
public class Entity {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String someProperty;
}
```

If I query the element with `findById()`, caching works as expected, a query is executed the first time, the cached version is used for subsequent queries. However, if I want to load elements by a query on `someProperty` like `findBySomeProperty(String)`, no caching happens whatsoever (which makes sense, as default caching only looks for the PK, I think).

How can I go on from this setup, to create caches for methods like `findBySomeProperty(String)`?

Answer (score 1):

This is a situation which calls for the use of and `@NaturalId`, `@NaturalIdCache`:

```java
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
@NaturalIdCache
@Entity
public class Entity {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @NaturalId
    private String someProperty;
}
```

and then the method `Session.bySimpleNaturalId()` may be used to retrieve the entity by its natural id.

Comment: Will this work if `someProperty` is not unique?

Comment: Nope, if it’s non-unique you need to use Hibernate’s query cache.